# ¿Como crear inputs names dinamicos? Django (MultiValueDictKeyError)

Tags: html, django

Muy buenas, estoy creando un sistema en Django el cual presenta varios Models. Los que son referentes a esta pregunta son los Models : "**PRESUPUESTOS_CERRADOS**", "**PRODUCTOS**" y "**PRODUCTOCANTIDAD**".

Model "PRODUCTOS":

```
class PRODUCTOS(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    precio = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    talle = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", null=True, blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(USUARIO, related_name="usuario_producto", on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=None, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.nombre} | Talle {self.talle}"
```

Model "PRESUPUESTOS_CERRADOS"

```
class PRESUPUESTOS_CERRADOS(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(CLIENTES, related_name="cliente_cerrado", on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None, blank=False)
    producto = models.ManyToManyField(PRODUCTOS, related_name="producto_cerrado", through='PRODUCTOCANTIDAD' ,default=None, blank=False)
    observacion = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=264)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    cliente_pago = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    factura = models.CharField(choices=cuentas, default='cuenta1', max_length=264)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID: {self.pk} cliente: {self.cliente.nombre}"
```

Model "PRODUCTOCANTIDAD":

```
class PRODUCTOCANTIDAD(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(PRODUCTOS, related_name="producto_cantidad", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    presupuesto = models.ForeignKey(PRESUPUESTOS_CERRADOS, related_name="presupuesto_cerrado", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
```

Ya cree en el views.py el formulario que crea un Presupuesto Cerrado. Ahora, mi dilema, es que no puedo lograr crear un formulario que permita editar el presupuesto. Mi idea era crear un formulario con todos los productos y cantidades del presupuesto.
**El problema** es que para mostrar todos los productos y sus cantidades tengo que usar un for loop con cada producto y su cantidad, estos valores se van a ver en un input que el usuario puede modificar, y de esa manera puede editarlo. Intente crear inputs con nombres dínamicos para que, luego, en el backend se pueda hacer un request.POST. Algo así:

```
        for producto in presupuesto.producto.all():
            producto_pk = request.POST[f"producto{producto.pk}"]
            productos_pk.append(producto_pk)
```

Me aparece el error "**MultiValueDictKey**". Seguramente porque no se permiten escribir formated strings dentro de los request.POST. ¿Como podría llegar a hacerlo?
Les muestro los inputs tambien:

```
            {% for producto in presupuesto.producto.all %}
                {% for cantidad in cantidades %}
                    {% if producto.pk == cantidad.producto.pk %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ producto.nombre }} | Talle {{ producto.talle }}</td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="producto{{producto_pk}}" value="{{ producto.pk }}">
                        <td><input type="number" value="{{ cantidad.cantidad }}" name="{{producto.pk}}"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="producto_eliminar" value="{{ producto.pk }}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el contador propio del bucle para añadir un sufijo a cada identificador:

```
{% for producto in presupuesto.producto.all %}
    {% for cantidad in cantidades %}
        {% if producto.pk == cantidad.producto.pk %}
            …
            <input type="hidden" 
                   name="producto{{producto_pk}}-{{ forloop.counter }}" 
                   value="{{ producto.pk }}"
                   id=producto{{ forloop.counter }}>
            …
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.